# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "ну" в выражении "Ну(,) конечно" в значении "разумеется"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не очень понял, какой смысл вы вкладываете в своё "разумеется".
Дело в том, что "ну" может быть частицей или междометием. Оба эти варианта в принцие возможны в вашей фразе даже с учетом вашего замечания.
В первом случае запятая не нужна, во втором - необходима.

Я могу только предположить, что вы имеете в виду вот этот случай:

Ну, частица: 
4.
**Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности, подчёркивает значение того или другого слова**. Ну конечно, это неправда. Ну какой холод! Ну что за жизнь: ни денег, ни чести, ни удовольствия. * Ну как не порадеть родному человечку (Грибоедов). 
(Кузнецов)
Тогда корректно без запятой.